# set SelectedItem of ComboBox to value of item in ListCollectionView

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox, selecteditem

I have a ListCollectionView which holds a bunch of Items of object Scene. One of the properties in Scene is Location.

When I navigate through the ListCollectionView I want to set the value of the Location property as SelectedItem in a comboBox in the View. Each time I go to a different item in the ListCollectionView I want to show the new location as SelectedItem in the comboBox.

I know how to make this work in a regular TextBox and TextBlock, but not in a ComboBox.

ViewModel

```
public ListCollectionView SceneCollectionView { get; set; }
private Scene CurrentScene
{
    get { return SceneCollectionView.CurrentItem as Scene; }
    set
    {
        SceneCollectionView.MoveCurrentTo(value);
        RaisePropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

View

```
<ComboBox  SelectedItem="{Binding SceneCollectionView/Location, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ItemsSource="{Binding AllLocations}}"/>
```

For textboxes following works perfectly, but not for comboBoxes

```
 <TextBox Text="{Binding SceneCollectionView/Location, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Any Idea how I can get the same behavior in for SelectedItem in ComboBox. I'm fairly new to coding in c#

Comment: What is the type of `Location` property?

Comment: It's a string property

Answer (score 0):

If all `Locations` defined in the supplied collection for your `ListCollectionView` exist in the `Locations` defined in your `AllLocations` property, then your code should work.

For example the following code along with the `ComboBox` you currently defined in your Xaml works as you expect:

Xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding SceneCollectionView/Location, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding AllLocations}"/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding SceneCollectionView/Location, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    <Button  Content="SelectNext" Click="Button_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

Code:

```
    public ListCollectionView SceneCollectionView { get; set; }
    public List<string> AllLocations { get; set; }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;

        var scenes = new List<Scene>();
        scenes.Add(new Scene { Location = "location1"});
        scenes.Add(new Scene { Location = "location2"});
        scenes.Add(new Scene { Location = "location3" });
        SceneCollectionView = new ListCollectionView(scenes);

        AllLocations = new List<string> { "location1", "location2", "location3" };
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SceneCollectionView.MoveCurrentToNext();
    }
```

In the above code, when you click the `Button`, Both `ComboBox.SelectedItem` and `TextBox.Text` changes to the next `Item.Location` defined in your `SceneCollectionView`.

Comment: This isn't utilizing MVVM